# std::cout doesn't show anything nor std::cin asking for input

Tags: c++

the code that this problem acours on is this

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char name[20];
    std::cout << "enter a name....";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "the name you entered was " << name; 
    system("pause");
}
```

it shows instead some weird stuff:

```
p 4464 70000 7000028207Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am using Dev-C++ IDE and its default compiler.

Why is that?

Comment: What input did you enter? If it had more than 19 characters undefined behaviour happened. (unless you use C++20)

Comment: <stdlib.h> or <cstdlib> should be included to call system() function.

Comment: You should use `std::cin.get();` instead of `system("pause");`

Comment: . . . . and an '<< endl' after printing name.  23 char in a 19 char bag!  That's why they invented string class!

Comment: If you insist on using character arrays, rather than `std::string`, please use `std::getline` or `std::cin.read` to limit the quantity of characters read.  If the User types in more than 20 characters without spaces, your array will overflow.

Comment: Can't reproduce this one. Could you add a few more details like the compiler and version, an IDE (and version) you are using or the terminal you're running the program in?

Comment: Like @user4581301 said, I can't reproduce this one either. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Include all the necessary information in your post. I.e. IDE, Compiler, etc.

Comment: I am using Dev-C++ IDE and its default compiler.

Comment: @churill I can't enter anything, it did not promt me any entr

Comment: Sorry, but that's hard to believe. I can't reproduce any errors with this code. There must be something else wrong then. Try changing `char name[20];` to `std::string name;` (and don't forget to `#include <string>`). You should use `std::string` anyway, but maybe you can find out if there is input comping from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you tell us the exact input of yours but the problem is probably that you do not account for the null terminator `'\0'`. When you use std::cin, it adds a null-terminator at the end of input stream. so if your input is 20 characters, you should actually use a char array of size 21. When you use 20, the program writes the null terminator past the end of array and it leads to an undefined behavior.